# OrderBy date pipe in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have pipe that sorts by array by date property.

Problem is that not each elements has property date in `args.key`. So there rows should be in bottom of list.

```
import {
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: 'sort'
})
export class ArraySortPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(records: Array < any > , args ? : {
    key: string,
    direction: boolean,
    type: "int" | "string" | "date"
  }): any {
    return records.sort(function (a: any, b: any) {
      if (args.type === 'date' && args.direction) {
        return new Date(a[args.key]).getTime() - new Date(b[args.key]).getTime();
      }
    });
  };
}
```

How to move properties without date to the bottom of list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ad another return values for the sorting function: if `a` doesn't have date, return -1. If `b` doesn't have date, return 1.

Like:

```
  transform(records: Array < any > , args ? : {
    key: string,
    direction: boolean,
    type: "int" | "string" | "date"
  }): any {
    return records.sort(function (a: any, b: any) {
      if (args.type === 'date' && args.direction) {
          if(!a[args.key]) {
              return -1;
          }

          if(!b[args.key]) {
              return 1;
          }

          return new Date(a[args.key]).getTime() - new Date(b[args.key]).getTime();
      }
    });
  };
```

(Direction not implemented).

Comment: it gives me always different result

Comment: Could you put it, along with example data, on stackblitz?